# Nginx with Shared Folder Virtualbox - Permission denied (Centos 7)

Tags: linux, nginx, virtualbox

I have a VPS, Centos 7 with virtualbox in windows 10 with shared folder working. The purpose of this is to have a workplace exactly like the production (I have a VPS ramnode) with nginx and php-fpm among others. To mount I use the command:

```
mount -t vboxsf web -o rw,uid=996,gid=994,fmode=777,dmode=777 /var/www/web
```

With the above command, the assembly is linked to the user and group named "**nginx**". I checked with **namei** and **"ls -la"**. Access is **drwxrwxr-x**.

Also, I've tried - redundantly - to force the release of access with the commands:

```
chown -R nginx:nginx /var/www/web
chmod 777 -R /var/www/web
```

Nginx and php-fpm are running under nginx user. But the nginx continues sending error "**`is forbidden (13: Permission denied)`**" to any file within the mounted folder.

I searched for a long time, even here, but I can not understand the reason for access failure. Thought to be a problem with virtualbox then I installed the "FileZilla Server" on windows, and mounted in using CentOS curlftpfs:

```
curlftpfs centos@myhost /var/www/web-o rw,uid=996,gid=994,umask=002
```

Mounting works, but the error persists. Nginx can not access the files. Thus, concludes that it is not virtualbox error, but the CentOS or nginx itself.

With the "**ps aux**" command, I found that both nginx and php-fpm run under "**nginx**" user.

I have also edited the **/etc/group** and **/etc/passwd**. I have also added the "nginx" user to "wheel" and "vboxsf" group. I also put the "vboxsf" and "nginx" group with root rights in "**/etc/sudoers**".

Environment:

- Host: Windows 10
- Virtualbox 5.0.26 r108824
- Centos 7.2
- Nginx 1.10.1
- PHP-FPM 5.6.24
- User ID: 996
- Group ID: 994

If I configure nginx root to another folder that is not vboxsf, everything works perfectly. So I'm out of ideas.

Anyone has any suggestions?

#### Addition 1:

Why not have more ideas, I installed centOS 7 Minimum again, only with nginx and vobx guest aditions to find out if it was a conflict, but the error persists.

#### Addition 2:

Since no one has provided any suggestions, I installed a VPS with Ubuntu 04.16 server, and configured the same way the CentOS 7 only with guest additions, nginx and php-fpm, and everything worked perfectly. Amazing! I can only have one conclusion: that this error is a CentOS 7 problem or incompatibility with the same vbofs. But I need it running on CentOS, the reason is irrelevant. If anyone has any suggestions, I am grateful.

Comment: I think it was incorrectly migrated.  My suspicion is that the /etc/export options are set as read-only or noexec is implied in CentOS and there's no setting to override it.  Also, the mount command seems to be using relative paths, and the file system appears to be a typo (vboxsf in the real command would break this if it is supposed to be vboxfs).  For readability, please convert all paths to absolute (or give the path from which you're executing the command).  Also please define each variable in the mount command.  For testing verify normal access first using ls and touch and rm.

Comment: For testing mounting in Linux, for items which will be added to /etc/fstab, I recommend adding them, then using the mount command to test mount.  Umount helps with unmounting.  Mount /mount/point triggers the OS to look in /etc/fstab for a line with /mount/mountpoint as source or destination.  Then it mounts that line.  Once mounted, cd to the mounted folder, list the contents.  Use touch file to add file.  Vim file, save changes.  Cat file.  Rm file.  If you can do all these you've verified the share.

Comment: Finally what is 'web' from the first mount command.  (And I think you meant addendum, not addiction).

Comment: Thank @Xalorous. The path provided "/var/www/web" is absolute. The word "web" after "vboxsf", specifies the name of the shared folder on the host and configured on virtualbox (not a path). The "vboxsf" name is correct and the syntax is correct; assembling work ( [link](https://gist.github.com/larsar/1687725) ). When logging in with my user can access content typically mounted: read, modify and execute, only the nginx server can not. I do not know why.  I'm not using /etc/fstab, but the /etc/rc.local to run the above commands at startup. The /etc/export is empty.

Comment: Have I not made the migration.